# C# error on button click

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, error-handling

I am developing a program with GUI using VS C#, when I click on a button that saves the table I get the error

```
>   Gipsy3.exe!Gipsy3.Database1DataSet1TableAdapters.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Gipsy3.Database1DataSet1 dataSet) Line 1262  C#
    Gipsy3.exe!Gipsy3.Form2.button3_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 44 + 0x1a bytes   C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(System.EventArgs e) + 0x62 bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs e) + 0x80 bytes   
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs mevent) + 0xac bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m, System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons button, int clicks) + 0x274 bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x890 bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0xeb bytes   
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x20 bytes   
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x11 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x39 bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x5e bytes 
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData) + 0x24d bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x155 bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x4a bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm) + 0x31 bytes  
    Gipsy3.exe!Gipsy3.Program.Main() Line 19 + 0x1d bytes   C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) + 0x6b bytes    
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() + 0x27 bytes  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state) + 0x6f bytes   
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0xa7 bytes  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x16 bytes  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x41 bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x44 bytes   
    [Native to Managed Transition]
```

This is the code that is generating the error

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Validate();
    this.itemsBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.database1DataSet1); // error on this line
}
```

I could not find the problem from the stack call above, what could be giving me this error?
If more information is needed, feel free to tell me so.

EDIT

```
catch (global::System.Exception ex) {
                workTransaction.Rollback();
                // ---- Restore the dataset -----------
                if (this.BackupDataSetBeforeUpdate) {
                    global::System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert((backupDataSet != null));
                    dataSet.Clear();
                    dataSet.Merge(backupDataSet);
                }
                else {
                    if ((0 < allAddedRows.Count)) {
                        global::System.Data.DataRow[] rows = new System.Data.DataRow[allAddedRows.Count];
                        allAddedRows.CopyTo(rows);
                        for (int i = 0; (i < rows.Length); i = (i + 1)) {
                            global::System.Data.DataRow row = rows[i];
                            row.AcceptChanges();
                            row.SetAdded();
                        }
                    }
                }
                throw ex; // exception thrown here
            }
            finally {
                if (workConnOpened) {
                    workConnection.Close();
                }
                if ((this._itemsTableAdapter != null)) {
                    this._itemsTableAdapter.Connection = ((global::System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection)(revertConnections[this._itemsTableAdapter]));
                    this._itemsTableAdapter.Transaction = null;
                }
                if ((0 < adaptersWithAcceptChangesDuringUpdate.Count)) {
                    global::System.Data.Common.DataAdapter[] adapters = new System.Data.Common.DataAdapter[adaptersWithAcceptChangesDuringUpdate.Count];
                    adaptersWithAcceptChangesDuringUpdate.CopyTo(adapters);
                    for (int i = 0; (i < adapters.Length); i = (i + 1)) {
                        global::System.Data.Common.DataAdapter adapter = adapters[i];
                        adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

The above is the code of `UpdateAll`, this was the part highlighted by VS, and the `throw ex;` was highlighted in yellow.

EDIT 2

After debugging, I was able to follow the lines of code that resulted in the exception being thrown.

```
// 
//---- Perform updates -----------
//
if ((this.UpdateOrder == UpdateOrderOption.UpdateInsertDelete)) {
  result = (result + this.UpdateUpdatedRows(dataSet, allChangedRows, allAddedRows));
  result = (result + this.UpdateInsertedRows(dataSet, allAddedRows));
} else {
  result = (result + this.UpdateInsertedRows(dataSet, allAddedRows));
  result = (result + this.UpdateUpdatedRows(dataSet, allChangedRows, allAddedRows)); // stepped in here
}
result = (result + this.UpdateDeletedRows(dataSet, allChangedRows));


/// <summary>
///Update rows in top-down order.
///</summary>
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
private int UpdateUpdatedRows(Database1DataSet1 dataSet, global::System.Collections.Generic.List<global::System.Data.DataRow> allChangedRows, global::System.Collections.Generic.List<global::System.Data.DataRow> allAddedRows) {
  int result = 0;
  if ((this._itemsTableAdapter != null)) {
    global::System.Data.DataRow[] updatedRows = dataSet.Items.Select(null, null, global::System.Data.DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent);
    updatedRows = this.GetRealUpdatedRows(updatedRows, allAddedRows);
    if (((updatedRows != null) && (0 < updatedRows.Length))) {
      result = (result + this._itemsTableAdapter.Update(updatedRows)); // stepped in here
      allChangedRows.AddRange(updatedRows);
    }
  }
  return result;
}


[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
[global::System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeywordAttribute("vs.data.TableAdapter")]
public virtual int Update(global::System.Data.DataRow[] dataRows) {
  return this.Adapter.Update(dataRows); // stepped in here
}
```

After stepping the above code, it goes through the catch statement, then skips the else and then the if statement and throws the exception.

Comment: Uhm, the Stack tells you where to look for the error, namly at: `Gipsy3.exe!Gipsy3.Database1DataSet1TableAdapters.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Gipsy3.Database1DataSet1 dataSet) Line 1262 `  Providing us with **that** piece of code might help. If it's a 3rd party library, then check the documentation. The button click is *not* the direct cause of the error...

Comment: What is the Exception type? That's more useful infomation in that case.

Comment: @MrPaulch I will post the code on top now.

Comment: @AlexSkiba I believe it was `global::System.Exception`

Comment: Just paste the message you're getting in exception. The code you've pasted shows us only how the exception is being handled and rethrown, not what threw it first. Use the debugger and get the line the error is being created.

Comment: @aizen92, and are you sure it is System.Exception? Anyway, after rethrowing the exception the stack trace is being cleared. So you should somehow display (or watch in the debugger) the stack trace of the initial exception.

Comment: @AlexSkiba Good point, seeing `throw ex` instead of `throw` always makes me nervous.

Comment: I added the functions resulting in the error by debugging, when it reaches the case statement, it will execute the first line of code, then it will go to the else, inside the else it will not execute the if statement and will throw the exception.